# Angular RxFormBuilder and Array of Strings

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to send a form to a backend which awaits the following JSON structure:

```
{
    name: "stringName",
    allowedFields: []
}
```

I have a model object for this

```
export class MyClass {
  @required()
  name: string;

  @propArray(String)
  allowedFields: Array<String>;
}
```

In the documentation they alway speak of custom objects but not the basic types like string Arrays:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators/v/1.2.2?activeTab=readme#more-information-about-validators-and-validation-decorators

In the html I am trying to use Bootstrap Switches to display a set of possible values which should be sent to the backend like this:

```
<div [formGroup]="field" *ngFor="let field of myFormGroup.controls.allowedFields.controls">
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
             [value]="field.memberName">
      <label class="custom-control-label">{{field.memberName}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Has anybody an idea on how to achieve to send an array of strings to the backend?
Cheers Maik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: This first part is NOT for your problem. In general, when you need a form must be like

```
form=new FormGroup({
  name:new FormControl(),
  allowedFields:new FormArray([]);
})
```

So make three function and a getter and declare a variable form:

```
form:FormGroup;

get allowedFields()
{
    return this.form.get('allowedFields') as FormArray;
}

getForm(data:any)
{
   data=data||{data:null,allowedFields:[]}
   return new FormGroup({
      name:new FormControl(data.name),
      allowedFields:new FormArray(data.allowedFields.map(x=>new FormControl(x)))
    }) 
}
addAllowedField(data:string)
{
    this.allowedFields.push(new FormControl(data));
}
removeAlloedField(index)
{
    this.allowedFields.removeAt(index)
}
```

Your .html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit(form)">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <div formArrayName="allowedFields">
    <button type="button" (click)="addAllowedField(null)">add</button>
  <div *ngFor="let control of allowedFields.controls;let i=index" >
    <input [formControlName]="i">
    <button type="button" (click)="removeAllowedField(i)">remove</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

See that you write `<div formArrayName="allowedFields">` and iterate over `allowedFields.controls` -is the "getter" defined in .ts. To control the "input" you can use `[formControlName]="i"` (or `[formControl]="control"` -control is the variable of the *ngFor

THIS PART is your about your QUESTION

But you want a series of checkbox and send and array with the values selected, so your form it's only two field

```
form=new FormGroup({
      name:new FormControl(),
      allowedFields:new FormControl();
})
```

See that "allowedFields" is a FormControl, NOT a FormArray.

A suppose you has an array of "allowedFields", make it an array of object, e.g.

```
fieldList=[
   {id:1,name:"field one"},
   {id:2,name:"field two"},
   {id:3,name:"field three"},
]
```

We are going to use inputs that not belong to the formGroup, yes [(ngModel)] in a ReactiveForms

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit(form)">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <div *ngFor="let item of fieldList;let i=index" >
    <input type="checkbox"
        [ngModel]="item.check" 
        (ngModelChange)="item.check=$event;setAllowedFields()"
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
    >{{item.name}}
  </div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

And a function

```
setAllowedFields()
{
   this.form.get('allowedFields').setValue(this.fieldList
           .filter(x=>x.checked)
           .map(x=>x.id))
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-md3lcy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update** for prepopulate the checks, as always, we has a function to return  the formGroup

```
getGroup(data)
{
   data=data || {name:'',allowedFields:[]}

   //prepopulate the data
   this.fieldList.forEach(x=>{
       x.check=data.indexOf(x.id>=0)
   })
   /* //or 
   allowedField.forEach(x=>{
     const field=this.fieldList.find(f=>f.id==x)
     if (field)
         field.check=true;
   })
   */
   return new FormGroup({
          name:new FormControl(data.name),
          allowedFields:new FormControl(data.allowedFields);
    })

}
```

You use as

```
   this.form=this.getGroup(null) //<--a empty form
   this.form=this.getGroup(data) //<-- a form with data
```

Comment: That's a valid solution, but this one is even shorter: https://github.com/rxweb/rxweb/issues/304

Comment: @Barzille, I like more my approach. You are using a helper variable "projectDomains" instead of a "computed" value. Use a computed value make that we needn't take care about discordance between the values, but of course your aproach is perfect valid

Comment: have you tried to prepopulate your checkboxes with values from the "server"? For me it seems it is not updating the checkboxes to the checked state.

Comment: I updated the answer to prepopulated the checkBox. I like has a function to create the formGroup that you call using as argument null or an object

Comment: Bit off Topic: I am using RxFormBuilder to populate a form having 100+ data items some are string,some boolean, some array and some objects..   this._formBuilder.formGroup(Data, data) works fine and return perfect rxFormGroup if items are not null. But in case item are not there then it return null is there anyway we can create defaults like empty array and empty objects ? I am not sure new to this hence asking. Please Help