# How strings' array into FormArray Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have array `(gifts)` of objects, after filled valid form by user, I want to check which checkboxes are checkIn, next push name of selected gifts into  `giftsArr` and on submit-action  push into `gifts FormArray`. I don't have idea how to do it.

```
 gifts = [
    {
      text: 'Pack as a gift',
      isClick: false,
    },
    {
      text: 'Add postcard',
      isClick: false,
    },
    {
      text: 'Provide 2% discount to the next time',
      isClick: false,
    }
]
```

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
    gifts: new FormArray([]),
  });
```

```
  onSubmit() {
    const checkedGifts = this.gifts.filter((gift) => gift.isClick === true);
    const giftsArr: any = [];
    checkedGifts.forEach((gift) => giftsArr.push(gift.text));

    // console.log(giftsArr) => ['Pack as a gift', 'Add postcard'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize each gift object as `FormGroup` instance in `gifts` `FormArray`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
    gifts: new FormArray([]),
  });

  this.initGiftsArrayControl();
}

initGiftsArrayControl() {
  for (let gift of this.gifts) {
    let formGroup = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(gift.text),
      value: new FormControl(gift.isClick),
    });

    this.giftsArrayControl.push(formGroup);
  }
}

get giftsArrayControl() {
  return this.signupForm.controls.gifts as FormArray;
}

getGiftName(control: AbstractControl<any, any>) {
  return (control as FormGroup).controls.name.value;
}
```

Next, the HTML template should be rendered each control from `gifts` `FormArray` as below:

```
<div [formGroup]="signupForm">
  <div formArrayName="gifts">
    <div *ngFor="let control of giftsArrayControl.controls; let i = index;">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="I">
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="value" />
        <label>{{ getGiftName(control) }}</label>
      </ng-container> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Lastly, to get the checked gift(s) by filtering the object with `value: true`:

```
onSubmit() {
  const checkedGifts = this.giftsArrayControl.value
    .filter((gift: any) => gift.value)
    .map((gift: any) => gift.name);

  console.log(checkedGifts);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-je1apz?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: Thre're not a good reason to create a formArray of FormGroup with the "value" and the "name". It's a well known problem. See one solution in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75925939/how-to-remove-commas-while-displaying-the-selected-checkboxes-in-angular/75926150#75926150). Really it's not necessary use a FormArray, we can use [(ngModel)] like this [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058310/angular-rxformbuilder-and-array-of-strings/61062429#61062429)

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, ya, seems I make it too complicated. Anyways thanks for the suggestion with the sample answers. =)